# Lightning component access in public community (no authentication)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I have added a Lightning component to a VF page and the lightning component is displaying fine when I access the VF page. But If I set this VF page as the community home page and try to access this without any authentication then the page fails to load the Lightning component. If I were to access the community with authentication then it works fine.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

**Lightning component:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="GLOBAL" >
    This is a component
</aura:component>
```

**Lightning App:**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:communityComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />

  <div id="lightning"/>
  <script >
      //inject the lightning component.
      $Lightning.use("c:communityApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:communityComponent",{},"lightning", function(cmp) {
              console.log('inside the component',cmp);
          });
        });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Error in the browser console:**

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you should have this in your app: `implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"` - I thought it was only for components. Try removing it from the app.

Comment: I did try it removing from the app as well but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you using the Napali template?

Comment: No, We are using the apex+ VF community

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the interface you are extending is wrong, you need to extend

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" 
implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
```

Please check the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_apps_public.htm). This feature was added as part of Spring '17.

Comment: Thanks! adding this implements made it possible to view the component viewable on community pages.